# How do you say on the one hand ... on the other hand?

Tags: conjunction

I found in a book that *quā ... qua* means *on the one hand ... on the other hand*, but I found no example.

Could you please provide a simple example?

Should a specific mood be used (subjunctive or indicative)?

Is there another conjunction to express that?

Comment: Perhaps "non solum ... sed etiam ...", though the meaning is not quite the same. Greek would use "men ... de ...".

Comment: ... and on the gripping hand, ...

Comment: @DavidRicherby : The OTHER other hand, eh?

Comment: My immediate thought also was *men…de* and it took me a minute to realize that wasn't Latin.

Answer (score 9):

**.A.** If there is a **contrast** of 'activity,' use  *hīc, illic;* for example ‘to go or to stay,’ 
*hīc abire, illic manere.*
If there is a contrast of ‘groups’ then *hic, haec, hoc,* and *ille, illa, illud,* as in this example from Cicero:

> *ergo ut hi miseri, sic illi contra beati.*
>   accordingly, as on the one hand these are wretched, so on the other these are happy.

If, by any chance, you mean literally on the one hand...on the other/ on this side...on the other
***Ex hac parte... ex alia parte...***

> Ezekiel 41;19 *faciem hominis iuxta palmam **ex hac parte** et faciem leonis iuxta palmam **ex alia parte** expressam per omnem domum in circuitu."*
>   the face of a man next to a palm on this side and the face of a lion next to a palm on the other side portrayed throughout the house all round.

**.B.** If there is **no real contrast**, *et...et* would be suitable. 
If there are several 'on the other hand's, then the following example from the Surtees Society publication on Finchale Priory for 1331 (p.xiv) is better.
***Imprimis...,   item...,   item...***  also with indicative.

> *Inprimis, apud Fynchal vj equi. Item xij boves. Item xvj porci. Item de frumento seminato xj qu. Item de pisis seminatis ij qu.*
>
> On the one hand, at Fynchale six horses. On the other hand twelve oxen.
>   Then sixteen pigs. Then eleven qu. of wheat for sowing. Then two qu.
>   of peas for sowing.

**Indicative** for statements; or direct questions. But maybe not if the alternatives are possible or hypothetical.